# enviar parametros desde un onclick en un fecht

Tags: javascript

estoy queriendo hacer un eccomerce, donde muestro todos los elementos que son llamados desde una api, y renderizarlo en la pagina. estoy practicando con los patrones de diseño y arme uno singleton, queria saber si esta bien, pero, mas alla de eso a la hora de tocar el boton de COMPRAR este me deberia llevar a la muestra de solo ese elemento, cosa que no sucede. Luego de eso, se deberia renderizar la pagina, donde solo se muestra el elemnto que tenga el id que seleccionamos. el error que me tira es de que no esta definido la funcion realizarAccion, ademas, de que cuando se clikea al elemento, si nos muestra los datos correspondientes a el elemento que seleccionamos

```
   class ObtenerDatos {
  static instancia;
  datos = [];

  // Constructor privado para asegurar una sola instancia
  constructor() {
    if (ObtenerDatos.instancia) {
      return ObtenerDatos.instancia;
    }

    ObtenerDatos.instancia = this;
    this.URL();
  }

  // Método para obtener datos desde la URL
  async URL() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
      const json = await response.json();
      this.datos = json;
      this.mostrarData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al obtener datos:', error);
    }
  }

  // Método para mostrar los datos
  mostrarData() {
    let body = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < this.datos.length; i++) {
      if (i % 3 === 0) {
        body += '<div class="row">';
      }

      body += `
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <h5 class="card-title">${this.datos[i].title} </h5>
            <img src="${this.datos[i].image}" class="card-img-top" style="max-height: 200px;"> 
            Price: ${this.datos[i].price}
            <div class="card-body" >
              <p class="card-text">${this.datos[i].description} </p>
              <a href="https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${this.datos[i].id}" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="realizarAccion(event, this)">comprar</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;

      if (i % 3 === 2 || i === this.datos.length - 1) {
        body += '</div>';
      }
    }

    document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = body;
  }
}

// Uso de la clase singleton
const instanciaDatos = new ObtenerDatos();

// Función que se ejecuta al hacer clic en el botón
async function realizarAccion(event, elemento) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const productId = elemento.getAttribute('href');
  const selectedProduct = await getProductById(productId);
  renderSelectedProduct(selectedProduct);
}

// Función para obtener el producto por ID
async function getProductById(productId) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${productId}`
    );
    const product = await response.json();
    return product;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al obtener producto por ID:', error);
  }
}

// Función para renderizar solo el producto seleccionado
function renderSelectedProduct(product) {
  const selectedProductHtml = `
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <h5 class="card-title">${product.title} </h5>
          <img src="${product.image}" class="card-img-top" style="max-height: 200px;"> 
          Price: ${product.price}
          <div class="card-body" style="max-height: 100px; overflow: hidden;">
            <p class="card-text">${product.description} </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;

  document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = selectedProductHtml;
}
```

Comment: un consejo, no utilizes nunca `innerHTML` porque compromete un serio riesgo de seguridad. Vas a tener que cambiar mucho codigo ya que la manera apropiada es crear elementos con `Document.createElement()` e ir anidando todo con `appendChild()`, para modificar texto utilizas `textContent`.

Comment: Esto: `const productId = elemento.getAttribute('href');` te va a devolver esta cadena: `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${this.datos[i].id}` con lo que sea el valor de `datos[i].id`. Luego, estás pasando toda esa cadena como parámetro a tu función `getProductById`, en la cual tienes la `url` del método `fetch` como una plantilla de cadena: `\`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${productId}\``, por lo cual el resultado de eso será: `https://fakestoreapi.com/products/https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${this.datos[i].id}`. Que sería una URL no válida. Cierto?

Comment: la idea es que si sea eso lo que se devuelve, pero, cuando reviso el error que tengo,me dice que la funcion realizarAccion no esta definida, por eso el programa no corre

Comment: Claro, porque al momento de instanciar tu Clase, esta función es externa a la misma, por lo donde tratas de usarla no está definida. Una forma de solucionar el problema es inyectar el método en el constructor de la Clase, pero `realizarAccion` depende a su vez de `getProductById`. Debes buscar la forma de inyectar ambas, para que los métodos de tu Clase puedan realizar estas llamadas. Por ejemplo: `constructor(private realizarAccion, private getProductById)` aunque luego debes ajustar la forma en que las usas dentro de tu clase. Saludos